# Some sites don't open while using my local DNS for name resolution

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

I recently installed and configured dnsmasq on an Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS. I can open my local web servers on my web browser but I get this error message (attached below).

If I change my DNS settings to let's say 8.8.8.8 or any public dns site, the website opens. There are also a couple of other sites I am finding difficult to open.

Could this be as a result of my configuration?

[image]

[My dnsmasq configuration file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTp226nf8s_UUnTggJ9fXH_D5xSTDw1PHwB8jrx9KWGBI5xuT-18Sn4G6A2DD_nTdodszzgpwDQBEwo/pub)

Comment: Obviously it looks like you've misconfigured the daemon.

Comment: Hi Artem, can you put me through how to correct this?

Comment: Well, I've no idea how you configured it and you don't say.

Comment: I will attach my configuration file to this

Comment: I have been able to figure that one out, I copied and paste the config on google docs and shared the link.

Comment: What result do you get from `host www.cv-library.co.uk`?

Comment: Hi ctrl-alt-del, I get this error 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' but if I changed my DNS server to any public DNS service it goes.